# Need to do the opposite of NSSelectorFromString()

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, cocoa, selector

In Cocoa, you can write `@selector(mySelectorNameWithObject:)` to get a compiled SEL, or at runtime, `NSSelectorFromString(@"mySelectorNameWithObject:")` with return a SEL. According to [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html):

> The only thing that makes the selector method name different from a plain string is that the compiler makes sure that selectors are unique.

But I can't seem to use a SEL object as a string without crashing. Is there a way to take a SEL and get back an `NSString` object? Basically I'm looking for the exact opposite of `NSSelectorFromString()`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Er…[`NSStringFromSelector`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromSelector)?

Comment: Heh.. That's great, wish I'd thought of it myself. Thank you.